# after insert trigger not firing after inserting with bcp

Tags: sql-server, trigger, bcp

content of csv file

```
TEST_1|sl2sysxbar301.dv.local|{'message_type': 2, 'super_evt_non_error': {'a0': 0, 'a1': 0, 'a2': 0, 'a3': 0, 'event': 5528, 'event_string': 'ENERGY_CTRL_RIGHT_PROX_DOWN', 'history_buffer_id': 3, 'history_buffer_string': 'HISTORY_BUFFER_UI_EVT', 'mid': 10, 'mid_string': 'CONSOLE1'}}|2021-06-26 05:03:20|
TEST_11|sl2sysxbar301.dv.local|{'message_type': 2, 'super_evt_non_error': {'a0': 393280, 'a1': 1, 'a2': 0, 'a3': 0, 'event': 8316, 'event_string': 'BP_FOLLOW_CHECK', 'history_buffer_id': 0, 'history_buffer_string': 'HISTORY_BUFFER_BP', 'mid': 6, 'mid_string': 'MTMR'}}|2021-06-26 05:03:20|
TEST_2|sl2sysxbar301.dv.local|{'message_type': 4, 'mmdsp_log': {'bp_start': {'bp_arg': 0.0, 'bp_code': 4097, 'bp_sn': 393300, 'mid': 6}, 'legacy_log_idx': 0}}|2021-06-26 05:03:20|
TEST_4|sl2sysxbar301.dv.local|{'message_type': 2, 'super_evt_non_error': {'a0': 267, 'a1': 0, 'a2': 0, 'a3': 0, 'event': 100001, 'event_string': 'INTER_MANIP', 'history_buffer_id': 3, 'history_buffer_string': 'HISTORY_BUFFER_UI_EVT', 'mid': 1, 'mid_string': 'AIM2'}}|2021-06-26 05:03:20|
```

here is bcp running via python

```
            p = subprocess.Popen(
                f'/opt/mssql-tools/bin/bcp {app.config.db_table_name} in {f.get("filename")}  -S {app.config.db_host},{app.config.db_port} -U {app.config.db_username} -P {app.config.db_password} -t  "|"  -c',
                shell=True,
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
            )
```

I have this table and trigger

```
CREATE TABLE [EVT_STREAM].[Event](
    [SystemName] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
    [Router] [varchar](128) NULL,
  [Event] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
  [ReceivedAt] [datetime] NOT NULL,
  [InsertedAt] [datetime] NULL
)ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [EVT_STREAM].[trg_EVT_STREAM]
   ON [EVT_STREAM].[Event]
   FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
insert into [EVT_STREAM].[Event](
  [InsertedAt]
)
  VALUES(
    GETUTCDATE()
    )
END
GO

ALTER TABLE [EVT_STREAM].[Event] ENABLE TRIGGER [trg_EVT_STREAM]
GO
```

basically I would like to update `[InsertedAt]` at the time when BCP runs and inserts CSV records in [EVT_STREAM].[Event] table.

Answer (score 4):

`bcp` has an option : *FIRE_TRIGGERS*  [link here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15)
(By default, triggers are not fired. To fire triggers explicitly, use the -h option with the FIRE_TRIGGERS hint.)
***-h"FIRE_TRIGGERS***"

- FIRE_TRIGGERS

*Specified with the in argument, any insert triggers defined on the destination table will run during the bulk-copy operation. If FIRE_TRIGGERS is not specified, no insert triggers will run. FIRE_TRIGGERS is ignored for the out, queryout, and format arguments.*

Answer (score 1):

Based on MBuschi's [suggestion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/294856):

> Isn't better to create a default with getdate() for the field [InsertedAt]?

I was able to find an alternate solution w/o need of having a separate trigger:

```
CREATE TABLE [EVT_STREAM].[Event](
[SystemName] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
[Router] [varchar](128) NULL,
[Event] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[ReceivedAt] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[InsertedAt] [datetime] NULL
)ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [EVT_STREAM].[Event]
ADD CONSTRAINT df_inserted_at
DEFAULT GETUTCDATE() FOR InsertedAt
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't better to create a default with getdate() for the field [InsertedAt]?

Comment: @MBuschi, I changed my approach and used, `getdate() for the field [InsertedAt]` it's working as intended. and solves my use case.